# How to get AppSetting values in startup by using services in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, extension-methods, startup

I want to get value of appsetting inside StartUp and also using services for saving them.
I create a static `IServiceCollection` method for `AddTransient` my custom service.
I define a `readonly` variable for keep the appsetting values. My problem is that, this service creates new instance for `readonly` variable, for all calling.how can I prevent this?

and I have a question that other extensions like `AddOpenIdConnect`, how to work with their configs, I mean how to save and use them?

this is startup:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
...

 services.AddMyIntegration(conf =>
            {
                conf.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Integration");
                conf.AgentApiAddress = Configuration["AgentApiAddress"];
            });

}
```

....

```
public static class MyExtension
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMyIntegration(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MyConstantsProvider> myConstantsProvider)
        {
            services.AddTransient((t) =>
            {
                return new MyService(myConstantsProvider);
            });

            return services;
        }
    }
```

this is my service:

```
public class MyService
    {
        public readonly MyConstantsProvider Provider;

        public MyService(Action<MyConstantsProvider> configure)
        {
            Provider = new MyConstantsProvider();
            configure(Provider);
        }
    }

 public class MyConstantsProvider
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string AgentApiAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

---

Update my question:
Finally I fixed my issue by add `MyConstantsProvider` as singletone instead of `MyService` so this creates new instance of variable at the first time in extension class:

```
public static class MyExtension
        {
            public static IServiceCollection AddMyIntegration(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MyConstantsProvider> myConstantsProvider)
            {
    var provider = new MyConstantsProvider();
                myConstantsProvider(provider);
                services.AddSingleton(provider);
                services.AddTransient<MyService>();
                return services;
            }
        }
```

this is MyService class:

```
public class MyService
    {
        public readonly MyConstantsProvider Provider;

        public MyService(MyConstantsProvider provider)
        {
            Provider = provider;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Transient`: a new instance is provided to every controller and every service. If you don't want to creates new instance for all calling, you can try to use `AddScoped` or `AddSingleton`. In your second question, Do you want to use service to save the value of appsetting? I don't understand why you want to do like it or i misunderstand your question, can you explain your second question in more detail？

Comment: @XinranShen you're right I can use AddSingleton but I want to add other method in MyService so I think It is not possible to run them in different thread. and about my second question, I am wondering to know how other extension work, and how they use parameters that they set in startup

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why we make it so complicated ? I just saw we're trying to read `appsettings` later in the application somewhere, and for this, the framework have default implementation to back us up.

Our app settings might look like

```json
{
    "Catalog": {
        "ConnectionString": "SomeConnection",
        "AgentApiAddress": "http://somewhere.dev"
    }
}
```

Then our class could be

```cs
public class MySetting
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string AgentApiAddress{ get; set; }
}
```

Config register it in startup (or somewhere we like in .net 6)

```cs
services.Configure<MySetting>(configuration.GetSection("Catalog"));
```

Retrive it later in the app via DI

```
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly MySetting _setting;

    public SomeService(IOptions<MySetting> config)
    {
        _setting = config.Value;
    }
}
```

For setting that can be change dynamically, take a look at [IOptionsMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#options-interfaces)

Or that might be some special case that I miss ?